# Container not extending with images

Tags: javascript, css, image, layout, z-index

I have a wordpress site where in order to have some rollover images I had to set the z-index out on the images. However I think because of this the container that they are supposed to be inside does not extend with them, and any text that you put into the container, even if entered after the images, always appears above the image.

The offending page can be found here: http://mysterybox.co/creatives/

Here's a screen capture of the problem:

[image]

Can anyone help me extend the black box out beyond the image?

Comment: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Answer (score 1):

Give `overflow: hidden;` for the `.post.page` class in your CSS. That will correct the error.

i.e.

**UPDATE**

```
.post.page {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    overflow: hidden; // this is the new addition
}
```

I just tested the change using Chrome inspector and it works correctly by extending beyond the image/animation you have on the center.